# Related rates problem: How rapidly is the area of an equilateral triangle increasing at the instant when each side is $69.28$ inches?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, related-rates

A metal plate in the shape of an equilateral triangle is being heated in such a way that each of the sides is increasing at the rate of ten inches per hour. How rapidly is the area increasing at the instant when each side is 69.28 inches?

$$A_{et} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}s^2.$$

So, 
$$\frac{dA_{et}}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}s\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(69.28 in)(10 \frac{in}{hr}) = 599.982399742 \frac{in^2}{hr} \approx 600 \frac{in^2}{hr}$$

In minutes,

$$600 \frac{in^2}{hr} * \frac{1 hr}{60 min} = 10 \frac{in^2}{min}.$$

The book's answer: $60 \frac{in^2}{min}$

Comment: The books answer is wrong.

Comment: Haha. Phew. I thought I was crazy. Thank you !

Comment: Please write an *informative* title that actually relates to the *content* of your question, to thus enable others to better find it later.

Comment: @PeterForeman Why would anyone trust a book written by someone who uses those crazy units of length?

Comment: Haha. Do you have a calculus book you would recommend in preparation for physics?